# getting java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfl

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

I have upgraded all the latest version google play services and firebase in my existing project which was being used in my gradle

I am getting this error at application launch.

2021-02-14 01:01:16.612 32420-32420/? E/014.basic.debu: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-02-14 01:01:20.386 32420-32455/com.softpauer.f1timingapp2014.basic.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ScionFrontendApi
Process: com.softpauer.f1timingapp2014.basic.debug, PID: 32420
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfl: void com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfl.zzN(java.lang.String, int, java.lang.Throwable, byte[], java.util.Map) failed to verify: void com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfl.zzN(java.lang.String, int, java.lang.Throwable, byte[], java.util.Map): [0x33] 'this' arg must be initialized (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfl' appears in /data/app/com.softpauer.f1timingapp2014.basic.debug-f13ILN_Uk6ai5SjSnt_SkA==/base.apk!classes4.dex)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfl.zzC(Unknown Source:0)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMeasurementDynamiteService.initialize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk@@18.0.2:2)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzak.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@@18.0.2:12)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbg.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@@18.0.2:2)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

[image]

latest Play services version updated

[image]

Firebase updated version in my gradle

[![][1]][1]

Comment: Please don't post text (errors, configs etc) as images

Comment: were you able to solve this?